# How can I give input with getpass to a Django app when deploying using Nginx, Gunicorn and systemd?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, systemd

I have a Django app that has key on disk which is encrypted using AES Cypher, and must be unencrypted in memory for use during the processes.

I have this line in `settings.py`:

```
AES_CIPHER_KEY = getpass("Enter AES cipher key: (leave blank if you don't need decryption)")
```

This is my `gunicorn.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

This is my `gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/samir/src/samirpy
ExecStart=/root/samir/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/log/gunicorn/samir.sock samir.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

This is `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'samir.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

What I would like to happen is when I update the code and restart the service using: `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn` it prompts for the key before starting the main process.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, services are **not** interactive and do not receive input from your terminal; their stdin is always connected to /dev/null. (Also, you have the service set up to start on boot via multi-user.target; are you going to type the password via IPMI/KVM every time the server boots?)

For passwords, systemd has an out-of-band method; see `man systemd-ask-password`. If your service uses this during startup (i.e. before it notifies systemd that it has finished starting), systemctl will show the password prompt for you – and during boot (when systemctl is not involved) you'll still be able to answer the password prompts without needing KVM.

---

Also, even that aside, "settings.py" sounds like it should be the *least* interactive piece of your program – user input prompts should **really** go elsewhere, not part of a constant definition. (That's like doing `#include "/dev/stdin"` in C...)

Comment: The server never restart and its a small application, so typing password is kind of one time thing and its not something I have to do on regular basis.
I have some seeds and passkeys that needs to be encrypted and decrypted and the key for the encryption shouldn't be saved anywhere. so the `getpass` thing was my only option.

Would you please shed more light on how to use  the `systemd-ask-password` method?

thanks.